# How do I make the custom module "Configure" option appear on the module list?

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I have written a simple module that implements `hook_menu()` (the added path is admin/settings/mymodule").

On the admin/modules page which lists all the present modules, there is no "Configure" link for my module. How do I implement it so that the link to "admin/settings/mymodule" is visible on the modules page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's done in the [module's ".info" file](http://drupal.org/node/542202), using the "configure" key.

```
name = Example module
description = Gives an example of a module.
core = 7.x
package = Views
dependencies[] = views
dependencies[] = panels
files[] = example.test
configure = admin/config/content/example
```